# Codeigniter 3 login check function not showing correct flashdata messages

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I am creating a login check function. But my two flash data messages are not setting correct.

1. If user has logged on and then if the session expires it should set this
   flash data message **Your session token has expired!**
2. And if the user has not logged on and tries to access a controller with out logging on
   then it should set this flashdata message **You need to login to
   access this site!**

For some reason it is always showing the second flashdata message.

> **Question:** How am I able to use the two flashdata messages properly.

**Controller:** Login.php
**Function:** check

```
public function check() {
    $uri_route = basename($this->router->directory) .'/'. $this->router->fetch_class();

    $route = isset($uri_route) ? $uri_route : '';

        $ignore = array(
            'common/login',
            'common/forgotten',
            'common/reset'
        );

        if (!in_array($route, $ignore)) {

            // $this->user->is_logged() returns the user id

            if ($this->user->is_logged()) {

                // $this->session->userdata('is_logged') returns true or false

                if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged')) {

                    // Redirects if the user is logged on and session has expired!

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Your session token has expired!');

                    redirect('admin/common/login');
                }

            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'You need to login to access this site!');

                redirect('admin/common/login');

            }
    }
```

I run function via codeigniter hook that way I do not have to add it on every controller.

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Login',
        'function' => 'check',
        'filename' => 'Login.php',
        'filepath' => 'modules/admin/controllers/common'
);
```

Comment: Be aware of that `$uri_route` will be isset every request because of concatenating slash. Second, following your description seems you are not logged in. Because it is what you get in else condition. Now, you need to check and/or post code when is this method used for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to check via the uri() is actually a very bad way of checking, also you should include login checks as a construct function not single.. here is what your function should look like:

```
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        // Allow some methods?
            $allowed = array(
                'some_method_in_this_controller',
                'other_method_in_this_controller',
            );
            if (!in_array($this->router->fetch_method(), $allowed)
            {
            redirect('login');
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for info but would like to be able to set the same 2 flash data messages. The uri_route gets the folder and controller name. I am using hooks to run the function so do not have to run it on every controller as I have added hook part on main question.

Comment: And I can see your code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920115/code-igniter-checking-if-user-logged-in-for-multiple-pages