# Check if user is logged in throughout the whole application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using ion_auth and I need to check if the user is logged in. ion auth provide the function `$this->ion_auth->logged_in()` so I am checking like this:

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        redirect('auth/login');
}
```

But I am posting this all over the Controller functions. how can I make it check everywhere?

Comment: You can add that in a constructor and extend that class. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920115/codeigniter-checking-if-user-logged-in-for-multiple-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is calling the function one time in the `__construct`

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        redirect('auth/login');
    } //if not logged in redirect, for all sections
}
```

Which will make it work on all of the functions. You can also extend core for it to work on all of the controllers `application/core/MY_Login.php`

```
<?php 

class MY_Login extends CI_Output {

  function check_login(){
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        redirect('auth/login');
    } //if not logged in redirect, for all sections
  }

}
```

Comment: while putting this in your controllers constructor is not a bad thing to do, extending the core in such ways is generally not a great idea, mostly because a derivation is just not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

While you could create your own controller like a MY_Controller that derives from the CI_Controller, this is really not what it is meant for.

CodeIgniter supports something called hooks, which are scripts that are run at specific moments, much like events. There exists a hook that is called every time any controller is called, without you having to implement anything in the controller itself.

Read more [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: this is the answer i want to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Create a core controller , the core controller will have a constructor and there you will do the check. Now all your controllers need to extends the core controller instead of the CI controller.  It will looks as follow:

application/controllers/your_controller.php

```
class Your_controller extends MY_Controller{
      function __construct(){
          parent::__construct(); 
     }
 }
```

application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
      function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
           if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
               redirect('auth/login');
           }
     }
 }
```

Doing this with every controller will run this function every time somebody visits any page, so make sure to change it so it works specificly on the area's you want it to do so. EG: Right now it will redirect you if you are on the login page aswell. Either have the login page not extends the core controller (Not recommended), or add another if() statement around the function.